# I have a serial Python application that takes hours to process, how can I decrease the time it takes to run?

Tags: python

Could someone please post a few examples of multi-threaded python? I am searching all over the internet but cannot find a simple, easy-to-replicate tutorial. Simple examples are fine.

I have written a program which takes a few hours to run serially--I am hoping I can bring it's run time down to minutes after multi-threading it.

Comment: Not, IMNSHO, a good question for the SO format. Asking for external resources on multi-threading in python would be better. And responders would be better using a blog or wiki somewhere.

Comment: CPython is multi-threaded but __not__ concurrent, none of the examples below that __don't__ use the multi-processing module will actually speed up your several hour process, they will in most cases slow it down incrementally because of all the context switching. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Comment: Apparently, no one likes lots of examples. :-) Comments are appreciated!

Comment: None of those examples are relevant to how to speed up a serial process that takes hours to complete. They are just __noise__.

Comment: "Could someone please post a few examples of multi-threaded python?" The eight examples show that Python can run some purposeful threads.

Comment: read the second paragraph "I have written a program which takes a few hours to run serially--I am hoping I can bring it's run time down to minutes after multi-threading it." --- nothing you posted addresses solving his actual problem. read for comprehension, rather than just trying to post as many answers to get as many rep points as you can. You said "Comments are appreciated" I guess they aren't really.

Comment: Actually, comments are appreciated. They give better understanding. As for "nothing you posted addresses solving his actual problem": without seeing his code, that is impossible to do. I gave Nick demonstrations on using threads; but to make his program run faster, you must analyze the code, what it is doing, and then propose how to restructure its execution to take advantage of threads and lead to a shorter execution time. The answers are not for my reputation; they are for Nick's benefit.

Answer (score 6):

I see you got a lot of examples, all so far from @Noctis, but I'm not sure how they're going to help you.  Addressing your question more directly: the only way multithreading can speed your application up, in today's CPython, is if your slow-down is due in good part to "blocking I/O" operations, e.g. due to interactions with (for example) DB servers, mail servers, websites, and so on.  (A powerful alternative to speed up I/O is asynchronous, AKA event-driven, programming, for which the richest Python framework is [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) -- but it can be harder to learn, if you've never done event-driven coding).

Even if you have many cores in your machine, one multi-threaded Python process will use only one of them at a time, except when it's executing specially coded extensions (typically in C, C++, Cython, and the like) which "release the GIL" (the global interpreter lock) when feasible.

If you *do* have many cores, `multiprocessing` (a module whose interface is designed to look a lot like `threading`) *can* indeed speed up your program.  There are many other packages supporting "symmetric multi-processor" distributed programming, see the list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing), but, out of all of them, `multiprocessing` is the one that comes as part of the standard library (a very convenient thing).  If you have multiple computers with a fast LAN between them, you should also consider the more general approach of [distributed](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributedProgramming) processing, which could let you use all of your available computers for the same task (some of these packages are also listed at the previous URL I gave, under the "cluster computing" header).

What speed-up you can get for any number of available cores or computers ultimately depends on the nature of your problems -- and, if the problems per se are suitable for it, then also of the algorithms and data structures you're using... not all will speed-up well (it varies between "embarassingly parallel" problems such as ray-tracing, which speed up linearly all the way, to "intrinsically serial" ones where 100 machines won't be any faster than one). So, it's hard to advise you further without understanding the nature of your problems; care to explain that?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question but:

Have you considered using Python's [multiprocessing module](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) instead? It works by forking new processes, which has slightly more overhead but can often be faster because it avoid contention problems with Python's global interpreter lock. The documentation is quite thorough and there are a number of other articles about it online.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/158/PLN/ParProcBook.pdf) is a good tutorial. Section 3.1.2 (page 72 of the tutorial) has a simple client/server example using threads.

Answer (score 1):

the C (CPython) implementation of Python is multi-threaded but **NOT** concurrent. Only one thread runs at a time, because of the [Global Interpeter Lock](http://blip.tv/file/2232410) (GIL). If you want true concurrency you can use the [mulitprocessing](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

None of the examples posted will help your multi-hour process run shorter, they will actually cause it to run L O N G E R.

Also you don't mention what you are actually doing, but you are probably I/O bound if you are reading/writing data to anything (network or disk). And concurrency will just exacerbate the problem if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1**

```
import thread

class sync:

    def __init__(self, threads):
        self.__threads = threads
        self.__count = 0
        self.__main = thread.allocate_lock()
        self.__exit = thread.allocate_lock()
        self.__exit.acquire()

    def sync(self):
        self.__main.acquire()
        self.__count += 1
        if self.__count < self.__threads:
            self.__main.release()
        else:
            self.__exit.release()
        self.__exit.acquire()
        self.__count -= 1
        if self.__count > 0:
            self.__exit.release()
        else:
            self.__main.release()

def example():
    def get_input(share):
        while share[0]:
            share[1] = raw_input('Please say something.\n')
            share[2].sync()
        share[3].sync()
    def do_output(share):
        while share[0]:
            share[2].sync()
            print 'You said, "%s"' % share[1]
        share[3].sync()
    share = [True, None, sync(2), sync(3)]
    thread.start_new_thread(get_input, (share,))
    thread.start_new_thread(do_output, (share,))
    import time; time.sleep(60)
    share[0] = False
    share[3].sync()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    example()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 2**

```
from os.path import basename
from Queue import Queue
from random import random
from sys import argv, exit
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

# for creating widgets
class Widget:
    pass

# for creating stacks
class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__stack = list()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__stack)
    def push(self, item):
        self.__stack.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.__stack.pop()

# provides an outline for the execution of the program
def main():
    # check and parse the command line arguments
    parse_sys_argv()
    # setup the variables used by the threads
    run_flag = [True]
    queue = Queue(argv[1])
    send = Stack()
    recv = Stack()
    # start the threads
    producer = Thread(target=produce, args=(run_flag, queue, send))
    consumer = Thread(target=consume, args=(run_flag, queue, recv, producer))
    producer.start()
    consumer.start()
    # let the threads do their work
    sleep(argv[2])
    run_flag[0] = False
    consumer.join()
    # verify that the solution was valid
    calculate_results(send, recv)

# parses and checks the command line arguments
def parse_sys_argv():
    try:
        # there should be two command line arguments
        assert len(argv) == 3
        # convert <buf_size> and check
        argv[1] = abs(int(argv[1]))
        assert argv[1] > 0
        # convert <run_time> and check
        argv[2] = abs(float(argv[2]))
        assert argv[2] > 0
    except:
        # print out usage information
        print basename(argv[0]),
        print '<buf_size> <run_time>'
        # exits the program
        exit(1)

# called by the producer thread
def produce(run_flag, queue, send):
    while run_flag[0]:
        # simulate production
        sleep(random())
        # put widget in buffer
        item = Widget()
        queue.put(item)
        send.push(item)

# called by the consumer thread
def consume(run_flag, queue, recv, producer):
    # consume items while running
    while run_flag[0]:
        do_consume(queue, recv)
    # empty the queue to allow maximum room
    while not queue.empty():
        do_consume(queue, recv)
    # wait for the producer to end
    producer.join()
    # consume any other items that might have been produced
    while not queue.empty():
        do_consume(queue, recv)

# executes one consumption operation
def do_consume(queue, recv):
    # get a widget from the queue
    recv.push(queue.get())
    # simulate consumption
    sleep(random())

# verifies that send and recv were equal
def calculate_results(send, recv):
    print 'Solution has',
    try:
        # make sure that send and recv have the same length
        assert len(send) == len(recv)
        # check all of the contents of send and recv
        while send:
            # check the identity of the items in send and recv
            assert send.pop() is recv.pop()
        print 'passed.'
    except:
        print 'failed.'

# starts the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The source to all those examples would not fit in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 3**

```
from os.path import basename
from Queue import Queue
from random import random, seed
from sys import argv, exit
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

################################################################################

class Widget:
    pass

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__stack = list()
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__stack)
    def push(self, item):
        self.__stack.append(item)
    def pop(self):
        return self.__stack.pop()

################################################################################

def main():
    parse_argv()
    run_flag, buffer_queue, producer_stack, consumer_stack, print_queue = [True], Queue(argv[1]), Stack(), Stack(), Queue()
    producer_thread = Thread(target=producer, args=(run_flag, argv[3], buffer_queue, producer_stack, print_queue))
    consumer_thread = Thread(target=consumer, args=(run_flag, producer_thread, buffer_queue, consumer_stack, argv[4], print_queue))
    printer_thread = Thread(target=printer, args=(run_flag, consumer_thread, print_queue))
    producer_thread.start()
    consumer_thread.start()
    printer_thread.start()
    sleep(argv[2])
    run_flag[0] = False
    printer_thread.join()
    check_results(producer_stack , consumer_stack)

def parse_argv():
    try:
        assert len(argv) > 4
        argv[1] = abs(int(argv[1]))
        argv[2] = abs(float(argv[2]))
        assert argv[1] and argv[2]
        argv[3] = abs(float(argv[3]))
        argv[4] = abs(float(argv[4]))
        if len(argv) > 5:
            seed(convert(' '.join(argv[5:])))
    except:
        print basename(argv[0]), '<buff_size> <main_time> <prod_time> <cons_time> [<seed>]'
        exit(1)

def convert(string):
    number = 1
    for character in string:
        number <<= 8
        number += ord(character)
    return number

def check_results(producer_stack , consumer_stack):
    print 'Solution has',
    try:
        assert len(producer_stack) == len(consumer_stack)
        while producer_stack:
            assert producer_stack.pop() is consumer_stack.pop()
        print 'passed.'
    except:
        print 'failed.'

################################################################################

def producer(run_flag, max_time, buffer_queue, producer_stack, print_queue):
    while run_flag[0]:
        sleep(random() * max_time)
        widget = Widget()
        buffer_queue.put(widget)
        producer_stack.push(widget)
        print_queue.put('Producer: %s Widget' % id(widget))

def consumer(run_flag, producer_thread, buffer_queue, consumer_stack, max_time, print_queue):
    while run_flag[0] or producer_thread.isAlive() or not buffer_queue.empty():
        widget = buffer_queue.get()
        consumer_stack.push(widget)
        sleep(random() * max_time)
        print_queue.put('Consumer: %s Widget' % id(widget))

def printer(run_flag, consumer_thread, print_queue):
    while run_flag[0] or consumer_thread.isAlive() or not print_queue.empty():
        if print_queue.empty():
            sleep(0.1)
        else:
            print print_queue.get()

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 4**

```
import socket
import sys
import thread

def main(setup, error):
    sys.stderr = file(error, 'a')
    for settings in parse(setup):
        thread.start_new_thread(server, settings)
    lock = thread.allocate_lock()
    lock.acquire()
    lock.acquire()

def parse(setup):
    settings = list()
    for line in file(setup):
        parts = line.split()
        settings.append((parts[0], int(parts[1]), int(parts[2])))
    return settings

def server(*settings):
    try:
        dock_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        dock_socket.bind(('', settings[2]))
        dock_socket.listen(5)
        while True:
            client_socket = dock_socket.accept()[0]
            server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server_socket.connect((settings[0], settings[1]))
            thread.start_new_thread(forward, (client_socket, server_socket))
            thread.start_new_thread(forward, (server_socket, client_socket))
    finally:
        thread.start_new_thread(server, settings)

def forward(source, destination):
    string = ' '
    while string:
        string = source.recv(1024)
        if string:
            destination.sendall(string)
        else:
            source.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD)
            destination.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main('proxy.ini', 'error.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 5**

```
# #include <windows.h>
import thread
# #include <math.h>
import math
# #include <stdio.h>
import sys
# #include <stdlib.h>
import time

# static int runFlag = TRUE;
runFlag = True

# void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
def main(argc, argv):
    global runFlag
    # unsigned int runTime
    # PYTHON: NO CODE

    # SYSTEMTIME now;
    # PYTHON: NO CODE
    # WORD stopTimeMinute, stopTimeSecond;
    # PYTHON: NO CODE

    # // Get command line argument, N
    try:
        N = abs(int(argv[1]))
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
    # // Get the time the threads should run, runtime
    try:
        runTime = abs(int(argv[2]))
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
    # // Calculate time to halt (learn better ways to do this later)
    # GetSystemTime(&now);
    now = time.localtime()
    # printf("mthread: Suite starting at system time
    #   %d:%d:%d\n", now.wHour, now.wMinute, now.wSecond);
    sys.stdout.write('mthread: Suite starting at system time %d:%d:%d\n' \
          % (now.tm_hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec))
    # stopTimeSecond = (now.wSecond + (WORD) runTime) % 60;
    stopTimeSecond = (now.tm_sec + runTime) % 60
    # stopTimeMinute = now.wMinute + (now.wSecond +
    #   (WORD) runTime) / 60;
    stopTimeMinute = now.tm_min + (now.tm_sec + runTime) / 60

    # // For 1 to N
    # for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for i in range(N):
        # // Create a new thread to execute simulated word
        thread.start_new_thread(threadWork, ())
        # Sleep(100);               // Let newly created thread run
        time.sleep(0.1)
    # }
    # PYTHON: NO CODE

    # // Cycle while children work ...
    # while (runFlag) {
    while runFlag:
        # GetSystemTime(&now);
        now = time.localtime()
        # if ((now.wMinute >= stopTimeMinute)
        #     &&
        #     (now.wSecond >= stopTimeSecond)
        #    )
        if now.tm_min >= stopTimeMinute \
           and now.tm_sec >= stopTimeSecond:
            # runFlag = FALSE;
            runFlag = False
        # Sleep(1000);
        time.sleep(1)
    # }
    # PYTHON: NO CODE
    # Sleep(5000);
    time.sleep(5)
# }
# PYTHON: NO CODE

# // The code executed by each worker thread (simulated work)
# DWORD WINAPI threadWork(LPVOID threadNo) {
def threadWork():
    threadNo = thread.get_ident()
    # // Local variables
    # double y;
    # PYTHON: NO CODE
    # const double x = 3.14159;
    x = 3.14159
    # const double e = 2.7183;
    e = 2.7183
    # int i;
    # PYTHON: NO CODE
    # const int napTime = 1000;             // in milliseconds
    napTime = 1000
    # const int busyTime = 40000;
    busyTime = 40000
    # DWORD result = 0;
    result = 0

    # // Create load
    # while (runFlag) {
    while runFlag:
        # // Parameterized processor burst phase
        # for (i = 0; i < busyTime; i++)
        for i in range(busyTime):
            # y = pow(x, e);
            y = math.pow(x, e)
        # // Parameterized sleep phase
        # Sleep(napTime);
        time.sleep(napTime / 1000.0)
        # // Write message to stdout
        sys.stdout.write('Thread %s just woke up.\n' % threadNo)
    # }
    # PYTHON: NO CODE
    # // Terminating
    # return result;
    return result
# }
# PYTHON: NO CODE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(len(sys.argv), sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 6**

```
import tkinter
import _thread
import time

EPOCH_DELTA = 946684800
MICREV_IN_DAY = 1000000
MILREV_IN_DAY = 1000

SECOND_IN_DAY = 86400
DAY_IN_WEEK = 7
WEEK_IN_MONTH = 4
MONTH_IN_SEASON = 3
SEASON_IN_YEAR = 4

SECOND_IN_WEEK = SECOND_IN_DAY * DAY_IN_WEEK
SECOND_IN_MONTH = SECOND_IN_WEEK * WEEK_IN_MONTH
SECOND_IN_SEASON = SECOND_IN_MONTH * MONTH_IN_SEASON
SECOND_IN_YEAR = SECOND_IN_SEASON * SEASON_IN_YEAR

def seconds():
    "Return seconds since the epoch."
    return time.time() - EPOCH_DELTA

def micrev(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to micrev."
    x = seconds % SECOND_IN_DAY * MICREV_IN_DAY / SECOND_IN_DAY % MILREV_IN_DAY
    return int(x)

def milrev(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to milrev."
    x = seconds % SECOND_IN_DAY * MILREV_IN_DAY / SECOND_IN_DAY
    return int(x)

def day(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to days."
    x = seconds / SECOND_IN_DAY % DAY_IN_WEEK
    return int(x)

def week(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to weeks."
    x = seconds / SECOND_IN_WEEK % WEEK_IN_MONTH
    return int(x)

def month(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to months."
    x = seconds / SECOND_IN_MONTH % MONTH_IN_SEASON
    return int(x)

def season(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to seasons."
    x = seconds / SECOND_IN_SEASON % SEASON_IN_YEAR
    return int(x)

def year(seconds):
    "Convert from seconds to years."
    x = seconds / SECOND_IN_YEAR
    return int(x)

UNITS = year, season, month, week, day, milrev, micrev

def text(seconds, spec='{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}.{4}.{5:03}.{6:03}', unit=UNITS):
    "Convert from seconds to text."
    return spec.format(*[func(seconds) for func in unit])

class Quantum_Timer:

    "Quantum_Timer(function, *args, **kwargs) -> Quantum_Timer"

    def __init__(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        "Initialize the Quantum_Timer object."
        self.__function = function
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs
        self.__thread = False
        self.__lock = _thread.allocate_lock()

    def start(self):
        "Start the Quantum_Timer object."
        with self.__lock:
            self.__active = True
            if not self.__thread:
                self.__thread = True
                _thread.start_new_thread(self.__run, ())

    def stop(self):
        "Stop the Quantum_Timer object."
        with self.__lock:
            self.__active = False

    def __run(self):
        "Private class method."
        while True:
            secs = time.clock()
            plus = secs + 0.0864
            over = plus % 0.0864
            diff = plus - secs - over
            time.sleep(diff)
            with self.__lock:
                if not self.__active:
                    self.__thread = False
                    break
            self.__function(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)

def main():
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.title('Time in Tessaressunago')
    secs = tkinter.StringVar()
    text = tkinter.Label(textvariable=secs, font=('helvetica', 16, 'bold'))
    text.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    thread = Quantum_Timer(update, secs)
    thread.start()
    root.mainloop()

def update(secs):
    s = seconds()
    t = text(s)
    p = 1000000000 * 1.01 ** (s / SECOND_IN_YEAR)
    secs.set('Time = {0}\nNational = {1}'.format(t, fix(p)))

def fix(number, sep=','):
    number = str(int(number))
    string = ''
    while number:
        string = number[-1] + string
        number = number[:-1]
        if number and not (len(string) + 1) % 4:
            string = sep + string
    return string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 7**

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8080

from Tkinter import *
import tkColorChooser

import socket
import thread
import cPickle

################################################################################

class ZSP:

    'ZSP(socket) -> ZSP'

    def __init__(self, socket):
        'Initialize the Zero SPOTS Protocol object.'
        self.__file = socket.makefile('b', 0)

    def send(self, obj):
        'Send one object.'
        cPickle.dump(obj, self.__file, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def recv(self):
        'Receive one object.'
        return cPickle.load(self.__file)

################################################################################

def main():
    global hold, fill, draw, look
    hold = []
    fill = '#000000'
    connect()
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Paint 2.0')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    upper = LabelFrame(root, text='Your Canvas')
    lower = LabelFrame(root, text='Their Canvas')
    draw = Canvas(upper, bg='#ffffff', width=400, height=300, highlightthickness=0)
    look = Canvas(lower, bg='#ffffff', width=400, height=300, highlightthickness=0)
    cursor = Button(upper, text='Cursor Color', command=change_cursor)
    canvas = Button(upper, text='Canvas Color', command=change_canvas)
    draw.bind('<Motion>', motion)
    draw.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', press)
    draw.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)
    draw.bind('<Button-3>', delete)
    upper.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    lower.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    draw.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2)
    look.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    cursor.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
    root.mainloop()

################################################################################

def connect():
    try:
        start_client()
    except:
        start_server()
    thread.start_new_thread(processor, ())

def start_client():
    global ZSP
    server = socket.socket()
    server.connect((HOST, PORT))
    ZSP = ZSP(server)

def start_server():
    global ZSP
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('', PORT))
    server.listen(1)
    ZSP = ZSP(server.accept()[0])

def processor():
    while True:
        func, args, kwargs = ZSP.recv()
        getattr(look, func)(*args, **kwargs)

def call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    ZSP.send((func, args, kwargs))

################################################################################

def change_cursor():
    global fill
    color = tkColorChooser.askcolor(color=fill)[1]
    if color is not None:
        fill = color

def change_canvas():
    color = tkColorChooser.askcolor(color=draw['bg'])[1]
    if color is not None:
        draw.config(bg=color)
        call('config', bg=color)

################################################################################

def motion(event):
    if hold:
        hold.extend([event.x, event.y])
        event.widget.create_line(hold[-4:], fill=fill, tag='TEMP')
        call('create_line', hold[-4:], fill=fill, tag='TEMP')

def press(event):
    global hold
    hold = [event.x, event.y]

def release(event):
    global hold
    if len(hold) > 2:
        event.widget.delete('TEMP')
        event.widget.create_line(hold, fill=fill, smooth=True)
        call('delete', 'TEMP')
        call('create_line', hold, fill=fill, smooth=True)
    hold = []

def delete(event):
    event.widget.delete(ALL)
    call('delete', ALL)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example 8**

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 8080

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import tkColorChooser
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.colorchooser as tkColorChooser

try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread

import socket
import pickle
import time
import sys

################################################################################

class ZSP:

    'ZSP(socket) -> ZSP'

    def __init__(self, socket):
        'Initialize the Zero SPOTS Protocol object.'
        self.__o_file = socket.makefile('bw', 0)
        self.__i_file = socket.makefile('br', 0)

    def send(self, obj):
        'Send one object.'
        pickle.dump(obj, self.__o_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

    def recv(self):
        'Receive one object.'
        return pickle.load(self.__i_file)

################################################################################

class QRP:

    'QRP(ZSP) -> QRP'

    def __init__(self, ZSP):
        'Initialize the Query/Reply Protocol object.'
        self.__ZSP = ZSP
        self.__error = None
        self.__Q_anchor = []
        self.__Q_packet = []
        self.__R_anchor = {}
        self.__Q_lock = thread.allocate_lock()
        self.__R_lock = thread.allocate_lock()
        thread.start_new_thread(self.__thread, ())

    def send_Q(self, ID, obj):
        'Send one query.'
        if self.__error:
            raise self.__error
        self.__ZSP.send((False, ID, obj))

    def recv_Q(self, timeout=None):
        'Receive one query.'
        if self.__error:
            raise self.__error
        if timeout is not None:
            if not isinstance(timeout, (float, int)):
                raise TypeError('timeout must be of type float or int')
            if not timeout >= 0:
                raise ValueError('timeout must be greater than or equal to 0')
        self.__Q_lock.acquire()
        try:
            try:
                if self.__Q_packet:
                    Q = True
                    ID, obj = self.__Q_packet.pop()
                else:
                    Q = False
                    anchor = [thread.allocate_lock()]
                    anchor[0].acquire()
                    self.__Q_anchor.append(anchor)
            finally:
                self.__Q_lock.release()
        except AttributeError:
            raise self.__error
        if Q:
            return ID, obj
        if timeout:
            thread.start_new_thread(self.__Q_thread, (timeout, anchor))
        anchor[0].acquire()
        try:
            Q = anchor[1]
        except IndexError:
            if self.__error:
                raise self.__error
            raise Warning
        return Q

    def send_R(self, ID, obj):
        'Send one reply.'
        if self.__error:
            raise self.__error
        self.__ZSP.send((True, ID, obj))

    def recv_R(self, ID, timeout=None):
        'Receive one reply.'
        if self.__error:
            raise self.__error
        if timeout is not None:
            if not isinstance(timeout, (float, int)):
                raise TypeError('timeout must be of type float or int')
            if not timeout >= 0:
                raise ValueError('timeout must be greater than or equal to 0')
        anchor = [thread.allocate_lock()]
        anchor[0].acquire()
        self.__R_lock.acquire()
        try:
            try:
                self.__R_anchor[ID] = anchor
            finally:
                self.__R_lock.release()
        except AttributeError:
            raise self.__error
        if timeout:
            thread.start_new_thread(self.__R_thread, (timeout, ID))
        anchor[0].acquire()
        try:
            R = anchor[1]
        except IndexError:
            if self.__error:
                raise self.__error
            raise Warning
        return R

    def __thread(self):
        'Private class method.'
        try:
            while True:
                R, ID, obj = self.__ZSP.recv()
                if R:
                    self.__R_lock.acquire()
                    if self.__R_anchor:
                        self.__R_anchor[ID].append(obj)
                        self.__R_anchor[ID][0].release()
                        del self.__R_anchor[ID]
                    self.__R_lock.release()
                else:
                    self.__Q_lock.acquire()
                    if self.__Q_anchor:
                        anchor = self.__Q_anchor.pop()
                        anchor.append((ID, obj))
                        anchor[0].release()
                    else:
                        self.__Q_packet.append((ID, obj))
                    self.__Q_lock.release()
        except Exception:
            error = sys.exc_info()[1]
            if isinstance(error, EOFError):
                self.__error = EOFError
            else:
                self.__error = IOError
            self.__Q_lock.acquire()
            for anchor in self.__Q_anchor:
                anchor[0].release()
            del self.__Q_anchor
            del self.__Q_packet
            self.__Q_lock.release()
            self.__R_lock.acquire()
            for key in self.__R_anchor:
                self.__R_anchor[key][0].release()
            del self.__R_anchor
            self.__R_lock.release()

    def __Q_thread(self, timeout, anchor):
        'Private class method.'
        time.sleep(timeout)
        self.__Q_lock.acquire()
        if not self.__error and anchor in self.__Q_anchor:
            anchor[0].release()
            self.__Q_anchor.remove(anchor)
        self.__Q_lock.release()

    def __R_thread(self, timeout, ID):
        'Private class method.'
        time.sleep(timeout)
        self.__R_lock.acquire()
        if not self.__error and ID in self.__R_anchor:
            self.__R_anchor[ID][0].release()
            del self.__R_anchor[ID]
        self.__R_lock.release()

################################################################################

class QRI:

    'QRI(QRP) -> QRI'

    def __init__(self, QRP):
        'Initialize the Query/Reply Interface object.'
        self.__QRP = QRP
        self.__ID = 0
        self.__lock = thread.allocate_lock()

    def call(self, obj, timeout=None):
        'Send one query and receive one reply.'
        self.__lock.acquire()
        ID = ''.join(chr(self.__ID >> shift & 0xFF) for shift in range(24, -8, -8))
        self.__ID = (self.__ID + 1) % (2 ** 32)
        self.__lock.release()
        self.__QRP.send_Q(ID, obj)
        return self.__QRP.recv_R(ID, timeout)

    def query(self, timeout=None):
        'Receive one query.'
        return self.__QRP.recv_Q(timeout)

    def reply(self, ID, obj):
        'Send one reply.'
        self.__QRP.send_R(ID, obj)

################################################################################

def qri(socket):
    'Construct a QRI object.'
    return QRI(QRP(ZSP(socket)))

################################################################################

def main():
    global hold, fill, draw, look
    hold = []
    fill = '#000000'
    connect()
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Paint 1.0')
    root.resizable(False, False)
    upper = LabelFrame(root, text='Your Canvas')
    lower = LabelFrame(root, text='Their Canvas')
    draw = Canvas(upper, bg='#ffffff', width=400, height=300, highlightthickness=0)
    look = Canvas(lower, bg='#ffffff', width=400, height=300, highlightthickness=0)
    cursor = Button(upper, text='Cursor Color', command=change_cursor)
    canvas = Button(upper, text='Canvas Color', command=change_canvas)
    draw.bind('<Motion>', motion)
    draw.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', press)
    draw.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', release)
    draw.bind('<Button-3>', delete)
    upper.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    lower.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    draw.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2)
    look.grid(padx=5, pady=5)
    cursor.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
    canvas.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=EW)
    root.mainloop()

################################################################################

def connect():
    try:
        start_client()
    except:
        start_server()
    thread.start_new_thread(processor, ())

def start_client():
    global QRI
    server = socket.socket()
    server.connect((HOST, PORT))
    QRI = qri(server)

def start_server():
    global QRI
    server = socket.socket()
    server.bind(('', PORT))
    server.listen(1)
    QRI = qri(server.accept()[0])

def processor():
    while True:
        ID, (func, args, kwargs) = QRI.query()
        getattr(look, func)(*args, **kwargs)

def call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        QRI.call((func, args, kwargs), 0.05)
    except:
        pass

################################################################################

def change_cursor():
    global fill
    color = tkColorChooser.askcolor(color=fill)[1]
    if color is not None:
        fill = color

def change_canvas():
    color = tkColorChooser.askcolor(color=draw['bg'])[1]
    if color is not None:
        draw['bg'] = color
        draw.config(bg=color)
        call('config', bg=color)

################################################################################

def motion(event):
    if hold:
        hold.extend([event.x, event.y])
        event.widget.create_line(hold[-4:], fill=fill, tag='TEMP')
        call('create_line', hold[-4:], fill=fill, tag='TEMP')

def press(event):
    global hold
    hold = [event.x, event.y]

def release(event):
    global hold
    if len(hold) > 2:
        event.widget.delete('TEMP')
        event.widget.create_line(hold, fill=fill, smooth=True)
        call('delete', 'TEMP')
        call('create_line', hold, fill=fill, smooth=True)
    hold = []

def delete(event):
    event.widget.delete(ALL)
    call('delete', ALL)

################################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```